# PHP Split comma separated string then add same value for each value in splitted array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

What the code in PHP to do that:

```
$string = '123,456,789,102'  
$value = '564'
```

How to split `$string` into an array then concatenated each value in the array with $value into two dimensional array, so the final result:

```
$result = (   
    (564,123),  
    (564, 456),  
    (564, 789),  
    (564, 102)              
)
```

So $result can be used in inserting multiple rows in mysql using PDO:

```
  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_user (id, bought) VALUES ((?,?),

       (?,?),
       (?,?),
       (?,?),
       (?,?),

            )');

       $stmt->execute($result);
```

note: id and bought columns are varchar

Comment: so what you have tried so minimal of your code?

Comment: check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// exploding & storing `$string` into an array. Array contains `$string` as strings.

```
 $s_array = explode(",", $string);

//to remove spaces

$spaces=array(); //to store space
$others=array(); //to store characters
foreach($s_array as $word)
{
    if($word=='')
    {
        array_push($spaces,$word); //spaces are stored into space array
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($others,$word);  //string variables are stored into others array
    }
}

$count=count($others);
```

Now use a for loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
for($j=0;$j<$count;$j++)
{
$result[$i][$j] = $value;
$result[$i][$j+1] = $others[$i];
}
}
```

If you want to convert the string array into integers....
do something like this...

```
$integerarray = array_map('intval', array_filter($others, 'is_numeric'));
foreach($integerarray as $var) 
 {
array_push($result, array($value, $var) );
}
```

and do the coding.

Comment: Thank you very much, for this detailed and very well explained answer. Please, can I use $others array when inserting multiple rows in my sql table using PDO.  


$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_user (id, bought) VALUES ((?,?),

(?,?),
(?,?),
(?,?),
(?,?),

)');

$stmt->execute($others);

Answer (score 2):

try `explode()` and `foreach()`

```
$string = '123,456,789,102';
$value = '564';
$arr = explode(',', $string);
foreach($arr as $v) {
  $newarr[] = array($value,$v);
}
print_r($newarr); //Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 564 [1] => 123 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 564 [1] => 456 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 564 [1] => 789 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 564 [1] => 102 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '123,456,789,102'  
$value = '564'
$string = explode(",",$string);
$result = array();
for ($i =0;$i<count($string);$i++)
{
$result[][0] = $value;
$result[][1] = $string[$i];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Give some explanation to your code. Code only answers are not appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you may use `explode` to  split `string` and do some looping to come up to your desirable array `$result`

```
$string = '123,456,789,102';
$value = '564';

$string = explode(",", $string);
$result = array();
foreach($string as $val) {
    array_push($result, array($value, $val) );
}

print_r($result);
```